# Cassandra create and load data atomicity

Tags: cassandra

I have got a web service which is looking for the last create table
[name_YYYYMMddHHmmss]
I have a persister job that creates and loads a table (insert or bulk)

Is there something that hides a table until it is fully loaded ?

First, I have created a technical table, it works but I will need one by keyspace (using `cassandraAuth`). I don’t like this.

I was thinking about tags, but it doesn’t seem to exist.
 - create a table with tag and modify or remove it when the table is loaded.

There is also the table comment option.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table comment is a good option. We use it for some service information about the table, e.g. table versions tracking.